# ES6: Create Strings using Template Literals - Freecodecamp

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I tried solving below problem, passed 3 out of 4 conditions. I'm not able to find anymore errors in my code below. But still it says "failuresList should be an array containing result failure messages."

Link:
 https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/create-strings-using-template-literals

**Problem:**
Use template literal syntax with backticks to create an array of list element (li) strings. Each list element's text should be one of the array elements from the failure property on the result object and have a class attribute with the value text-warning. The makeList function should return the array of list item strings.

Use an iterator method (any kind of loop) to get the desired output

```
[
  '<li class="text-warning">no-var</li>',
  '<li class="text-warning">var-on-top</li>',
  '<li class="text-warning">linebreak</li>'
]
```

1. Not passed : failuresList should be an array containing result failure messages.
2. Passed : failuresList should be equal to the specified output.
3. Passed : Template strings and expression interpolation should be used.
4. Passed : An iterator should be used.

Below is my code so far :

```
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["id-blacklist", "no-dup-keys"]
};

function makeList(arr) {
  "use strict";
 
 
  // Only change code below this line
  const resultDisplayArray = (arr) =>{
    let failure = [];
   for (let element of arr) {
      failure.push(`<li class="text-warning">${element}</li>`);
    }
  
    return failure;
    
  };
  // Only change code above this line

  return resultDisplayArray(arr);
}

const resultDisplayArray = makeList(result.failure);
console.log(resultDisplayArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra `resultDisplayArray` function within the `makeList` function. Just loop through the array!

```
function makeList(arr) {
  // Only change code below this line
  const failureItems = [];
  for (let element of arr) {
      failureItems.push(`<li class="text-warning">${element}</li>`);
  }
  // Only change code above this line
  return failureItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the `map` method here.

```js
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["no-extra-semi", "no-dup-keys"]
};
function makeList(arr) {
  // Only change code below this line
  const failureItems = result.failure.map(element => `<li class="text-warning">${element}</li>`);
  // Only change code above this line
  return failureItems;
}

const failuresList = makeList(result.failure);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'll refer to the questions in 2 ways: how to fix your code and I'll suggest a clean way to solve the problem.

1. The problem has nothing to do with the correctness of the code, but with the fact, you changed the name of the variable that's being checked. You should have kept the variable "failuresList" in the global scope to be the one that holds the result array. But instead, you changed it to "resultDisplayArray". **copy-pasting your code and change the name only, resulted with all tests passed"**
   (I'm referring to the line before the last line in your code)
2. You shouldn't have wrapped the array creation with the inner function "resultDisplayArray". this is what "makeList" is for, the inner function is redundant and therefore should not be there.
3. This is how I would have done it:

```js
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["no-extra-semi", "no-dup-keys"]
};

function makeList(arr) {
  // Only change code below this line
  const failureItems = arr.map(curr => `<li class="text-warning">${curr}</li>`);
  // Only change code above this line

  return failureItems;
}

const failuresList = makeList(result.failure);
console.log(failuresList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["no-extra-semi", "no-dup-keys"]
};

function makeList(arr) {
  // Only change code below this line
  const failureItems = [];

for (let i = 0; i < result.failure.length; i++){
  failureItems.push(`<li class="text-warning">${result.failure[i]}</li>`);
}
  // Only change code above this line

  return failureItems;
}

const failuresList = makeList(result.failure);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["no-extra-semi", "no-dup-keys"]
};
function makeList(arr) {
  // Only change code below this line
  const failureItems = [];
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
   failureItems.push(`<li class="text-warning">${arr[i]}</li>`);
  }
  // Only change code above this line
  return failureItems;
}
const failuresList = makeList(result.failure);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this simple solution below:

```
const result = {
        success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
        failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
        skipped: ["no-extra-semi", "no-dup-keys"]
      };

      function makeList(arr) {

        // Only change code below this line
        const failureItems = [];

        for (i=0; i < result.failure.length; i++) {
          failureItems[i] = `<li class="text-warning">${result.failure[i]}</li>`;
        }

        // Only change code above this line
        return failureItems;
      }
      
      const failuresList = makeList(result.failure);
      console.log(failuresList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started my long journey of learning JavaScript, but as I understand it, I need to use the knowledge that I have at the moment.

```js
const result = {
  success: ["max-length", "no-amd", "prefer-arrow-functions"],
  failure: ["no-var", "var-on-top", "linebreak"],
  skipped: ["no-extra-semi", "no-dup-keys"]
};
function makeList(arr) {
  // Only change code below this line
  const failureItems = [];
  for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    failureItems.push(`<li class="text-warning">${arr[i]}</li>`)
  }
  // Only change code above this line

  return failureItems;
}

const failuresList = makeList(result.failure);
console.log(makeList(result.failure))
```